# Searching nearest location with latitude and longitude in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, geolocation, filtering

I am currently developing a web app which can calculate the nearest airport from a specific location entered in Google Maps using latitude and longitude. At the moment I have a function that sort of calculates my question, but gives me wrong information when setting the location to certain airports.

Current function to calculate nearest airport:

```
var goalLat = Number(this.from.geometry.location.lat());
var goalLong = Number(this.from.geometry.location.lng());

var closest = this.airports.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
     return (Math.abs(curr.lat - goalLat) < Math.abs(prev.lat - goalLat) &&       Math.abs(curr.long - goalLong) < Math.abs(prev.long - goalLong) ? curr       : prev);
});
```

This function works 50%, since it does know Schiphol airport is near Amsterdam. But when searching Cologne the function thinks Maastricht is more near than Cologne Bonn Airport even though this is not the case. Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide what library you are using, and what are the exact outputs you are getting given a specific input. This would help us a lot in helping you out.

Comment: I am using the Google Maps vue3 library. I have an input where you can enter your address in, which returns a latitude and a longitude. Next I have a database filled with all airports in the world, including latitude and longitude. Eventually I want to use the latitude and longitude given by the Google Maps location and compare every single latitude and longitude from the airports database and retrieve the airport which is the nearest for the given location. I use the function stated above to loop through and pick the nearest airport, but it sometimes returns wrong airports as stated above.